# Square matrix A as P+iQ where P and Q are hermitian matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

[This is the link to the answer of the question "Show that every square matrix A can be expressed in one and only one way as P+iQ where P and Q are hermitian matrix"](http://www.ques10.com/p/6038/show-that-every-square-matrix-can-be-uniquely-expr/)

I understand the solution of the website but problem is :
After the statement "To prove uniqueness: Let, A=R+S, where R is a Hermitian and S is a skew-Hermitian matrix, be another representation of A."

$A^\theta=(R+S)^\theta=R-S$  ....(okay i got it)

$-----------------------$
But i dont understand how we get the following two terms.

$\frac{1}{2}$$(A+A^\theta)=\frac{1}{2}[(R+S)+(R-S)]$

$\frac{1}{2}$$(A-A^\theta)=\frac{1}{2}[(R+S)-(R-S)]$

Comment: Is it pretty straight forward? $A^\theta = R -S$, $A = R + S$, hence the followed two equations.